# ViewDataDictionary passing in Model

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-2, partial-views

```
using (var writer = new StringWriter())
                        {
                            viewPath += (viewName + ".aspx");
                            var view = new WebFormView(viewPath);
                            var vdd = new ViewDataDictionary<T>(indication.Model);
                            var viewCxt = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, view, vdd, new TempDataDictionary(), writer);
                            viewCxt.View.Render(viewCxt, writer);
                            return Json(
                                new { 
                                    html = writer.ToString()
                                    });
                        }
```

Error is:

```
Error   66  The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewDataDictionary<T>.ViewDataDictionary(T)' has some invalid arguments    C:\SVN\k2\AppTeamTrunk\web\Chatham.Web\Controllers\IndicationsController.cs 318 39  Chatham.Web
```

I'm not sure how to get the view to render passing in the model.

Any help?

Comment: What are you trying to do here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think you need the `<T>` argument on this line

```
var vdd = new ViewDataDictionary<T>(indication.Model);
```